# How do I get the Explore and Stream section from the SoundCloud API

Tags: soundcloud

I can't seem to find the section in their [api reference](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference).  I tried it as a searchquery but it doesn't seem to work. api.soundcloud.com/stream or /explore return a 404, so that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats actually not a part of the public API.

But its quite easy to grab your call from the dev console.

Thats an example call from my user:

https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/stream?user_id=e87647259112403eaa239b6e2c510e46&sc_a_id=e87647259112403eaa239b6e2c510e46&user_urn=soundcloud%3Ausers%3A1672444&promoted_playlist=true&limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea&app_version=a089efd

To make that call work, you need to modify the headers.

These answers may help you:

- [Retrieving the "recommended" playlist via API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388089/retrieving-the-recommended-playlist-via-api-call/26390142#26390142)
- [soundcloud: Is api-v2 allowed to be used and is there documentation on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253633/soundcloud-is-api-v2-allowed-to-be-used-and-is-there-documentation-on-it/29258809#29258809)
- [How to get "all" tracks related to an artist with Souncloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299826/how-to-get-all-tracks-related-to-an-artist-with-souncloud-api/32308716#32308716)

Using these endpoints does not go inline with SoundClouds TOS.

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was a v2 api of soundcloud. I found out a bit more about it online. Sadly I havent found any documentation yet, but I hope [this](https://github.com/gillesdemey/soundcloud-v2) might help if any others are looking for it aswell

Comment: Why is user_id so long and not the standard integer? Also what are the sc_a_id, user_urn, and app_version parameters?